# How to use two models in one view - Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I want to create component based on com_weblinks.

This component will display categories and links on single page.

In 3.0 I don't understand **how I can use 2 models (categories models and links model) in one view.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First approach**

I did this by modifying the controller as follows (this is the controller for user)

```
function doThis(){ // the action in the controller "user" 
    // We will add a second model "bills"
    $model = $this->getModel ( 'user' ); // get first model
    $view  = $this->getView  ( 'user', 'html'  ); // get view we want to use
    $view->setModel( $model, true );  // true is for the default model  
    $billsModel = &$this->getModel ( 'bills' ); // get second model     
    $view->setModel( $billsModel );             
    $view->display(); // now our view has both models at hand           
}
```

In the view you can then simply do your operations on the models

```
function display($tpl = null){              
    $userModel = &$this->getModel(); // get default model
    $billsModel = &$this->getModel('bills'); // get second model

    // do something nice with the models

    parent::display($tpl); // now display the layout            
}
```

**Alternative approach**

In the view directly load the model:

```
function display($tpl = null){
 // assuming the model's class is MycomponentModelBills 
 // second paramater is the model prefix    
        $actionsModel = JModel::getInstance('bills', 'MycomponentModel'); 
}
```

Comment: remove the `&` from the Alternative approach ;)

Comment: for  the Alternative in 3.0, will be right  JModelLegacy::getInstance($type, $prefix = '', $config = array()). But thanks anyway